# Haskell - Custom functor instance on data type with function constructor

Tags: haskell, functor

I am having trouble writing my own instance of functor for a custom data type (that I cannot change). The data types are defined as:

```
data Foo a = Baz String (Qux -> Foo a) | Bar a
data Qux = None | Quux String
```

My problem is with writing a functor for the `Foo` type. Specifically, I'm not sure how to properly apply my functor function `f` to the function in the `Foo`. I was thinking of somehow calling the function in the constructor, but since I don't have any `Qux`'s available for use, I'm stuck.

```
instance Functor Foo where
    fmap f (Bar a) = Bar (f a)
    fmap f (Baz s ???) = Baz s (???) -- What goes here?

    -- Clearly, something like this doesn't work
    -- fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s (f g) 

    -- I've also tried something like this, but I'm not sure where to go from there
    -- fmap f (Baz s (None   -> Bar b)) = Baz s (f b) ???
    -- fmap f (Baz s (Quux x -> Bar b)) = Baz s ???
```

Comment: The first part is easy: `Baz` is a product of two types, so you just need to pattern match on `Baz s g` (where `g :: Qux -> Foo a`). What to *do* with `g` is the tricky part :)

Comment: As often in Haskell, the way to think about this is just to "follow the types". You have a function `f :: a -> b`, a function (which I'll call `g`) of type `Qux -> Foo a`, and you want a function of type `Qux -> Foo b`. I'm pretty sure there's only one way to do this with what you've got here - and to see it, don't be afraid to use recursion ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by completing the left side of this equation. We can write `g` to bind your function to a variable.

`fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s (???)`

Then, we need to fill in the question marks with another function, that takes a `Qux` and returns a `Foo b`.

`fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s (\q -> ???)`

We can only do one thing with `q`, which is apply `g` to it.

`fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s (\q -> g q)`

However, this gives us a `Foo a`, but we need a `Foo b`! We don't have a function to do that. We do, however, have `f`, which takes an `a` and returns a `b`. If only there were a way to take `a -> b` and turn it into `Foo a -> Foo b`... oh wait, there is, it's called `fmap`!

`fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s (\q -> fmap f (g q))`

If you want to write the function in point free notation (https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree), you can do this instead.

`fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s (fmap f . g)`

Comment: Many thanks! This was what I was having problems with. I forgot that I could use lambdas like that.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the types:

```
fmap f (Baz s g) = GOAL
   -- f    :: a -> b
   -- s    :: String
   -- g    :: Qux -> Foo a
   -- GOAL :: Foo b
```

So we're looking for a `Foo b` (the GOAL line).  We can make one with either `Bar` or `Baz`.  `fmap` should preserve the structure so it ought to be `Baz`.  The `String` argument to `Baz` probably should not change, it's only the second argument that poses the problem.

```
fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s GOAL
   -- f    :: a -> b
   -- s    :: String
   -- g    :: Qux -> Foo a
   -- GOAL :: Qux -> Foo b
```

Now we have to make a `Qux -> Foo b`.  If you need to make a function, lambda is the essential tool (there are others, but lambda is the granddaddy).  So make a lambda:

```
fmap f (Baz s g) = Baz s (\x -> GOAL)
   -- f    :: a -> b
   -- s    :: String
   -- g    :: Qux -> Foo a
   -- x    :: Qux          <-- NEW
   -- GOAL :: Foo b
```

Notice that we now have an `x :: Qux` to work with.  Using `g` and `x` we can make a `Foo a`, and then using `fmap f` *recursively*<sup>1</sup> we can make the required `Foo b`.

Notice how I'm just filling out the expression one tiny step at a time, replacing unknown arguments with goals, then taking a step back to consider what variables I have in scope and what their types are.  Continue doing this until a path to the goal is clear.

---

<sup>1</sup> A recursive type will usually have a corresponding recursive `fmap` definition.  The place the recursion happens in `fmap` corresponds exactly to the way the type is recursive.